# Open .xlsb with ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, .net-core, exceldatareader, xlsb

ExcelDataReader documentation says that it can open .xlsb files.

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    // Auto-detect format, supports:
    //  - Binary Excel files (2.0-2003 format; *.xls)
    //  - OpenXml Excel files (2007 format; *.xlsx, *.xlsb)
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
    {
        // Choose one of either 1 or 2:

        // 1. Use the reader methods
        do
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // reader.GetDouble(0);
            }
        } while (reader.NextResult());

        // 2. Use the AsDataSet extension method
        var result = reader.AsDataSet();

        // The result of each spreadsheet is in result.Tables
    }
}
```

But when I try to open a .xlsb stream, it gives an error saying that it can't open a zip file.

I have tried to see if any free third party lib that can convert xlsb to XLS, without any luck.

Comment: Why don't u open it in excel and from there do "Save as" and select the "xls" extension?

Comment: @DA that won't help at all - `xls` is obsolete for over 15 years. `xlsx` and `xlsb` are ZIP packages. It's quite possible the file is *not* an Excel file at all, but a text file with a fake extension

Comment: That error means that either the file is corrupt or isn't an Excel file to begin with. Excel files are ZIP packages containing XML (xlsx) or binary (xlsb) files. Can you open the file in Excel at all?

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message? Which version of ExcelDataReader are you using?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - Sure, but with such assumptions any provided answer in this context may be wrong...

Comment: At this moment in time you have to use the latest 3.7.0 prerelease version of ExcelDataReader for XSLB support. https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/releases

Comment: Any updates on this? I get the same error for any xlsb files. Tried specifying the reader as a binary reader as well but same issue.